# Not able to display Chinese character in application

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column in which Chinese characters are stored and the column contains a customer name in Chinese language.

When I select the column in SSMS I can see all the names in Chinese language but when the same is done from application the application displays '??????' in all the fields of that columns.

I tried to collate the column with 'Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AS' in a select statement still no use.

Does anyone knows what should I do to display Chinese character in the application.

Comment: Could you say witch type of application you are making?

Comment: I am not familiar with the application much but this is a internal webapplication for logistics domain where employees can view all customer details. So for China region Customer name are stored in Chinese language which are displayed as '????' in webapplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue due to application problem. its not an sql server issue. check in application. if ?????? comes in sql server, then only its sql server issue. hence its not an sql server issue